# Mantener el ultimo estado registrado de un Spinner Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, spinner, sharedpreferences

estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual tiene unos botones switch, los cuales tienen `SharedPreferences` para que cuando se cierre la aplicación y se vuelva a abrir, los botones previamente activados, lo sigan estando.

SharedPreferences en la clase MainActivity:

```
private Spinner spipol;
    private Switch quim, fil, fis, tri, esp, engl, inf, eti, reli, est, pol, dib, edf, mate;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, sharfil, sharquim, shardfis, shartrig, sharesp, sharemater, sharing, sharinf, shareti, sharrel, sharest, sharpol, sharedf;
    public static final String ex1 = "switch1";
    public static final String ex = "switch";

 dib = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("dib", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        dib.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(ex, false));
        dib.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    editor.putBoolean(ex, true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean(ex, false);
                }
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
```

Lo que necesito es saber como puedo hacer algo parecido a lo que tengo con los botones switch, pero con mi spinner:

```
       String [] opciones = {"","Tarea corta","Taller","Estudiar","Preguntas","Repasar"};
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, opciones);
       spipol.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

Busque en internet como hacerlo, pero en todos los lugares que veia, usaban un botón para guardar, lo que me gustaría saber es si puedo hacer esto sin necesidad de la implementación de este botón.

Edit: Probé esto pero no funciono:

```
 spipol.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CapturaSpinner = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                index = position;
                System.out.println("Indice:"+index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }
public void guardarPreference(Context context, int index) {
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    editor.putInt("Dato", index);
    System.out.println("Indice:"+index);
    editor.apply();   
}

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui intente declara la variable con la ayuda que brinda android studio, pero no funciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto aparece en el Build: error: `illegal start of expression public void obtenerPreference (Context Context context;`

Y el logcat no para de registrar mensajes del sistema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes un punto y coma en el medio de la declaración de un método??? Eso en Java no es válido por ningún lado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque te falta implementarlo. Este es tu evento de selección:

```
spipol.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //debes añadir esta línea para guardar, no lo veo en tu código así que lo añadí
                guardarPreference(getApplicationContext(), spipol.getSelectedItemPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Y este es tu evento para guardarlo:

```
public void guardarPreference(Context context, int index) {
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences(getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
    editor.putInt("Dato", index);
    System.out.println("Indice:"+index);
    editor.apply();   
}
```

Ahora bien, esto solo lo guarda por lo que para que cuando inicies tu actividad el valor guardado nno se mostrará. Para mostrarlo, simplemente crea un método que lo muestre desde la preferencia y añade la línea:

```
 public int obtenerPreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getInt("Dato", 0); //0 sería el valor default.
}
```

Y lo añades a tu onCreate() por ejemplo:

```
spipol.setSelection(obtenerPreference(getApplicacionContext());
```

**ACTUALIZACIóN:**

Dejo el cómo deberías tener tu clase "`Preference`" este es un claro ejemplo de cómo la debes tener para su correcto funcionamiento.

```
public class PreferenciaIdSpinner {
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public PreferenciaIdSpinner(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void guardarValorSpinner(int valor){//El contexto no es necesario, yo lo añadí por un uso particular que le doy. Puedes quitarlo, no habrá problemas
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("ejemplo", MODE_PRIVATE);//ejemplo sería el lugar donde se almacenaría el dato
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("idSpinner", valor);//idSpinner es el nombre con el que se va a almacenar el dato
        editor.apply(); 
    }

    public int obtenerPreference(){ //El contexto no es necesario, yo lo añadí por un uso particular que le doy. Puedes quitarlo, no habrá problemas
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("ejemplo", MODE_PRIVATE); //ejemplo sería el lugar donde se almacenaría el dato
        int valorSeleccion = pref.getInt("idSpinner", 0); //idSpinner es el nombre con el que se va a almacenar el dato
        return valorSeleccion; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, aun así, tengo un error en la parte del `(Context context)`, creo que esto es por el xml, o tal vez por que no he declarado esa variable, pero el caso, es que tengo ese error y no se como solucionarlo, me seria de gran ayuda si me dices que puedo hacer.

Comment: ¿Qué clase de error tienes? ¿Puedes añadir los imagen? ¿El logcat que dice?

Comment: Perdón por la demora, últimamente no he tenido tiempo. Ya actualice la pregunta con la clase de error que tengo, gracias por la paciencia.

Comment: BIen, he visto tu problema. Pero, para corroborar que sea cierto lo que pienso, ¿Puedes añadir toda la clase de tu preference? Actualizaré mi respuesta, controla sila tienes "parecida"